# Is it advisable to run Lint on "file bases" when speeding up the build time is the main goal?

Tags: android, android-lint

We're trying to speed up our build time on the CI so we're considering only run static analytical tools on those files that actually contain changes. We know that there is a Lint CLI that allows passing single files as input, but we don't know if there are side effects on doing this. For example, it seems that it will be lost the Lint issue `ExtraTranslation`, which checks that a given string declared in supported languages is also declared in the default language -because this is a comparative analysis and running Lint in file bases makes this impossible.

So, is it advisable to run Lint on file bases when speeding up the build time is the main goal?

Thanks!